# Call one function from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still a novice with web technologies and I have a few questions in line with the following code.

I'm trying to call a function getDetails() from another javascript function displayTable().
displayTable() gets invoked on clicking the button 'My CD Facts'.

Well, its not working for me. I guess its some thing daft but I'm not able to figure out. I tried to diagnose it with firebug and it says getDetails() is not defined.

Also, I have a basic css file for displaying the table in a particular style. That's not working either. Is it because I linked it in the body and I'm using it in the head?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlDoc;

function displayTable()
{
var artistName;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlDoc.open("GET","Artists.xml",false);
  xmlDoc.send("");
  xmlDoc=xmlDoc.responseXML;
  }
else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load("Artists.xml");
  }

document.write("<table class=\"artistTable\" border='1'>");
document.write("<th>Artist</th> <th>Title</th>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
  artistName = x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.write("<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:getDetails(artistName );\">");
  document.write(artistName);
  document.write("</a></td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
}

function getDetails(artistName )
{
    alert(artistName);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<form>
<input type="button" value="My CD Facts" onclick="displayTable()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

getDetails() is not a Javascript buit-in function. It is a user defined function. The people that wrote the book Head First Ajax defined their version of the getDetails() on page 24.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write("<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:getDetails(" + artistName + ");\">");
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of minor mistakes.

1. document.write clears off the rest of the page, so the script you have slotted in has gone.
   You could try instead of using document.write, using document.getElementById("id").InnerHtml to a div / span. (im not a js expert - so you may want to google that.), instead, for the document.writing.
2. what rony said, but with a couple of single inverted commas.

   document.write("< tr>< td>< a href=\"javascript:getDetails('" + artist + "');\">");